# Convert and round (Seconds to Minutes) with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field on my table which represents seconds, I want to convert to minutes

```
Select (100/60) as Minute from MyTable
-> 1.66
```

How can I get 1 minute and 40 seconds `00:01:40` and then round to `00:02:00` and if `00:01:23` round to `00:01:30`

Using Mysql.

Comment: Are you trying to round to the nearest 30 seconds and display as `mm:ss`?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to round to the nearest 30 seconds and display as mm:ss

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways of rounding, using integer arithmetic and avoiding floating points, a value to the nearest thirty seconds...

- ((seconds + 15) DIV 30) * 30
- (seconds + 15) - (seconds + 15) % 30

The latter is longer, but in terms of cpu time should be faster.

You can then use `SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)` to get the format `hh:mm:ss`, and take the right 5 characters if you *really* need `hh:mm`.

If you wanted to avoid `SEC_TO_TIME(seconds)`, you can build up the string yourself.

- minutes = total_seconds DIV 60
- seconds = total_seconds % 60
- final string = `LPAD(minutes, 2, '0') | ':' | LPAD(seconds, 2, '0')`

Comment: I think you need to rework that first example with some parenthesis and either a `FLOOR()`ing or a `DIV`ing...

Comment: @pilcrow - Parenthesis, yup, my mistake.  No need for FLOOR, etc though, but must ensure that all values are INTEGERS - It's provided as an example on how to achieve this with integer arithmetic as it's significantly less CPU intensive than floating point arithmetic.

Comment: Yes, you must ensure results are integral.  :)  Your first example gives the _wrong value_ under MySQL if "seconds" is, say, 83.  The `/` operator yields a DECIMAL even if both operands are integral.  So, you must either `FLOOR()` the quotient, set [@@div_precision_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_div_precision_increment) to zero (yuck!), or use `DIV` in place of `/`.

Answer (score 3):

i am not sure about how to `round` it but you can convert `seconds` into `time` i.e `hh:mm:ss` format using `SEC_TO_TIME(totaltime)`

Comment: The supported range for time is from '-838:59:59' to '838:59:59', w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp

Answer (score 0):

Desired result :

```
A = 30
B = 60
C = 90
D = 120
```

---

```
select 

(25 + 15)-(25 + 15) % 30 as A,

(32 + 15)-(32 + 15) % 30 as B,

(90 + 15)-(90 + 15) % 30 as C,

(100 + 15)-(100 + 15) % 30 as D
```

Result :

```
A = 30

B = 30

C = 90

D = 90
```

I try with this:

```
select 

30* ceil(30/30) as A,

30* ceil(32/30) as B,

30* ceil(90/30) as C,

30* ceil(100/30) as D
```

Result :

```
A = 30

B = 60

C = 90

D = 120
```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Ceiling introduces floating point arithmetic, it's wasting cpu cycles at present.  If you don't want to round to the ***nearest*** 30 seconds, but actually *always round up*, then I'd use this instead...  `(x + 29) - (x + 29) % 30`

Answer (score -3):

You can simply write your own function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

But I'd rather do that in a programing language (PHP, Python, C), not on the database side.

Comment: it is not an answer of asked question